# How to manually supply passphrase to autossh, preferably on login

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, ssh-tunneling, gnome-keyring

I want to run a bash script (as root) that among other things establishes reverse SSH tunnel using `autossh`. The SSH key has a passphrase.

1. Ideally I would like to have to login as root in terminal and the passphrase would be retrieved from a keyring (the computer has Gnome), or something like this, and supplied to `autossh` (if needs be I can set SSH passphrase and the root password to be the same).
2. If #1 is absolutely impossible I can do two things - (a) login and (b) run `ssh-agent /bin/bash` and then provide the passphrase `ssh-add`.

However even manual input of the passphrase as mentioned in #2 doesn't work.
If I run `ssh-agent/ssh-add` (as mentioned above), SSH itself works:
`ssh -f -N -T -R 8888:localhost:22 -p 9999 tunnel@example.org`
But:
`autossh -M 7777 -f -N -T -R 8888:localhost:22 -p 9999 tunnel@example.org`
doesn't work.

How can I troubleshoot #2 and then ideally implement also #1?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?